# How to get total size of folders with find and du?

Tags: bash, shell, debian

I'm trying to get the size of the directories named "bak" with find and du.

I do that : `find -name bak -type d -exec du -ch '{}' \;`

But it returns the size for each folder named "bak" not the total.

Anyway to get them ? Thanks :)

Comment: I recommend using `awk` to compute the end sum (using `du` without `-h`)

Comment: @Alex, why would that be preferred?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use [`xargs(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) instead of `-exec`:

```
find . -name bak -type d | xargs du -ch
```

`-exec` executes the command for each file found (check the [`find(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) documentation).  Piping to `xargs` lets you aggregate those filenames and only run `du` once.  You could also do:

```
find -name bak -type d -exec du -ch '{}' \; +
```

If your version of `find` supports it.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Ubuntu 12.04. Piping the results of this suggestion to awk does work: | awk '{ sum+=$1} END {print sum}'

Comment: To speed things up you could add the max depth if you know the structure of directories you're looking for: `find . -maxdepth 3 -type d -name bak | xargs du -ch --max-depth=0`

Comment: it is `du -ch {} +` not `du -ch {} \; +`

Answer (score 9):

If there are many files, using `-exec ... +` may be executed [multiple times](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152717/when-will-find-exec-command-execute-command-multiple-times) and you would get multiple subtotals.

An alternative is to pipe the result of find:

```
find . -name bak -type d -print0 | du -ch --files0-from=-
```

Comment: I think this answer is the simplest solution to the original question. It becomes even more versatile by using `tr` and `grep` in the pipe:

`find . -name bak | grep -v 'not this' | grep -v 'not that' | tr "\n" "\0" | du -hcs --files0-from=-`

Answer (score 4):

Try `du -hcs`. From the manpage:

```
 -s, --summarize
      display only a total for each argument
```

Comment: Same issue, with -s or without.

Comment: Hmm, did you try `find -name bak -type d -exec du -ch {} +`?

Comment: Tried, it seems that my version of find doesn't support it.

Answer (score 3):

Feed *du* with the results of *find*:

```
du -shc $(find . -name bak -type d)
```