# How to use du to take the paths from stdin and calculate the total size?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get total size of folders with find & du](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794791/get-total-size-of-folders-with-find-du)

I can use du like this to get the file size of each file from `stdin`

```
find . -name "*.java" -exec du -h {} \;
```

But I can't get the total size.. Does anyone have ideas about that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answered here:

[How to get total size of folders with find and du?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794791/get-total-size-of-folders-with-find-du)

> Use xargs(1) instead of -exec:
>
> `find . -name bak -type d | xargs du -ch`
>
> executes the command for each file found (check the find(1) documentation). Piping to xargs lets you aggregate those filenames and
>   only run du once.

In your case it would be:

```
find . -name "*.java" | xargs du -ch
```

Options:

```
   -c, --total
          produce a grand total
```

Comment: Strange, this works with 10,000 files but for 100,000 files it gives a really small (wrong) total.